# How to copy and append the records of from 1 CSV file to another CSV file and also add some inputs to the same CSV file during executiontime in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I need to copy or select the entire row of data from the CSV1 and append or paste the data to CSV2. And also Add some input like 'D' to "Action" Column of CSV2 on the fly means during the load test exectuion in the Jmeter.

CSV files:

[image: CSV1]

[image: CSV2]

Answer (score 0):

In JMeter you can only:

1. Read values from the CSV file using [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)
2. Write values to [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) using [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) or to arbitrary file using [Flexible File Writer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FlexibleFileWriter/)

If you want to copy the CSV file in JMeter you can use the following [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) code in a suitable [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223):

```
new File('/path/to/destination.csv').bytes = new File('/path/to/source.csv').bytes
```

It's also possible to add some data to the file like:

```
def lines = new File('/path/to/source.csv').readLines()
//edit the lines according to your requirement here
File destination = new File('/path/to/destination/file.csv')
destination.withWriter { out ->
    lines.each { out.println it }
}
```

Comment: If you dont mind can any one kindly provide entire groovy script code because I am not good enough in it. Please try to understand :)

Comment: I don't mind at all but 1. [this is not a code writing service](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372166/we-are-not-a-code-writing-service-comments-are-they-the-good-the-bad-or-the-u), you're supposed to try to implement something yourself and ask a question if you face an issue. 2. You're [not supposed to upload code in form of images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)